# How do I turn Java code into spark code?

Tags: java, apache-spark, stringtokenizer

a.txt:

```
{27|2|0|1|49|6|N926
 50|2|0|1|49|10|N760
 36|1|0|1|50|8|nncd}
```

String Tokenizing with Java code is easy. But I do not know String Tokenizing in spark code.
How can I do StringTokenizing based on `'|'` with spark code?

Below my Java code *(label points to a.txt)*

```
String tokenizer st = new String tokenizer (label, "|");    
String attrName  = st.nextElement (). ToString ();    
Integer treeLevel = new Integer (st.nextElement (). ToString ());
String valueStr = st.nextElement (). ToString ();
```

How to replace spark code?  I am using Eclipse.

Comment: what is the information you need to extract in the output. Spark works based on RDD. You can read the `a.txt` using `textFile` API in spark RDD and then use `map` transformation to tarnsform as per the output required. Share what you have tried.